# SSO(Single Sign On) in java web applications

Tags: java, single-sign-on

I have multiple java web applications all having their login functionalities. I want to apply SSO(Single Sign On) on them irrespective by any method.
I have spent last 2 days on finding a solution to it, but I have no result.
Please anyone can help me on that.
My requirement is:
           1.If user logs onto a single application he would be automatically logged onto other applications.
Sorry for my English and Thanks in advance.

Comment: google JBOSS keycloack. Keycloack is Java based open source SSO framework and JBOSS supports it out of the box. Download JBOSS Wildfly and deploy many apps on it. It's just direction for googling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If applications are in a Windows intranet and use windows logins, [Waffle](http://waffle.codeplex.com/) will do the job. Otherwise develop your own simple ticket granting service to provide SSO among your applications.

Update:

All of your apps have to have filters. Filter sends the session/cookie data(if available) in order to verify, to your SSO service whether the incoming request with the principle is already granted or not. If the session or cookie is not associateed with a ticket, then you redirect to the login page. If the request is about to login, then filter sends them in to SSO service, verify user and password with your database, and add an entry to SSO MAP, saying "this user just logged in". So it will send a ticket for that login. Ticket means just a random generated id. If the SSO service could not able to validate the user, then no entry will be there in the SSO MAP and will send failure error to your filter.
So your user validation goes in to a separate service which I just named as SSO service.
You will have to remove idle entries from SSO MAP.

Read about how SSO works, you will understand.

Comment: Thank You for your help.But as I am totally new here, I even don't know how to generate ticket granting service.Please help....